Can a Ben Pakuah be brought as a Korban?
Since shechita is not required would that prohibit bringing a ben pakuah as a korban? Or would you just schect it anyway and continue on?

Chullin 74b takes it as a given that a ben pakuah is unfit to be a korban.
Rashi (s.v. degamar) explains that this is because it is was born via caesarean section (yotzei dofen), which renders it unfit to be a korban.
Tosafot (s.v. degamar) argue, and explain that it is unfit as a korban because it is viewed as having already been slaughtered.
